# htaccess redirect is passing variables to the new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I stop a redirect from passing variables to the new url?

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/camper-trailers/light-off-road/details/0/(.*) http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/camper-trailers.html? [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/camper-trailers/light-off-road/details/0/(.*) http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/camper-trailers.html? [L,R=301,QSD]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/camper-trailers/light-off-road/details/0/(.*) http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/camper-trailers.html?
```

They all keep the variables, and the first two add an extra ?

Example:

http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/camper-trailers.html??format=html

Comment: Which version of apache are you using QSA,QSD are only valid for 2.4.
Also is the ```?``` really a ```?``` (if you copied it from somewhere it may be unicode rather than ascii)

Comment: I'm not sure which version it is, how can I find that out? I typed in the ? myself

Comment: ```apachectl -v``` will show you the version

Comment: The apache version is 2.2.31